# Angular 2 Web Api sending Auth token

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Does anyone know what may be preventing my token from being read by my API,
Yes, Cors is enabled on my api, and I can call my end point from Fiddler(and see my authenticated user successfully like that). I have
made sure that IIS accepts all verbs, and I am passing my auth token like so:

```
public Post = (endpoint: string, filter?: Type): Observable<Type[]> => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization",'Bearer ' + this._cookieService.get('access_token'));
    headers.append("Content-Type","application/json");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    debugger;

      return this._http.post(Config.API + endpoint, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <Type>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I am sending:
[image]

However, on my server I get:
[image]

Hitting the endpoint with fiddler and an auth token like so:
Authorization => Bearer WiZJQv9TJHEixcdI4FS94PUWsQlwkslKBXKq_fBbeup66XA0OuhG9jkyHbJ1ONKykxEtNHf-WpETb5r4Vj_42GvBu2SPSM_rWhs_svwzBesa9ozpkgRBVm_BvNShiUDGlD4T5-X2s4PFC1ssxQ4a74qb8ZfASG8nd8OS1hGxwaYC5e0uBZWxPvHqGEicJVOJ6qd-ANb56wkwavCnt1PUr4BK0X6z1UWCAhSf8iZGC_w8wmDr7sVQqEkxdoRQPH8_PFVNivbq9qPO1kLDMrsDTchohLR1spET9IxHvWgrTwV8D5tNysj_ZH4vxp_yXjYoCyOvzvC-nU4poX8NUPIh2Z-3MgxjbTMGA35sn3TMZo1XvpFcdChXSQFHig8hzHqXjfj_K8czM3xaIgjx-RgzLVcl_A-i-7vGFY9TcmLBqC8-mQ4eTOqgW6j4cm9N5mfk6VmIlCOAWJu2k1cixwZHxwOsvdkbBQJP8bbnjUeYJ1k
results in:[image]

I have been at this for hours, Would someone please give me a pointer?
Thanks,
-Kevin

Comment: what is the expected header from the service side?

Comment: let me grab a pic of it from when i use fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, I omitted the body of the post. Here is a corrected post:

```
return this._http.post(Config.API + endpoint, filter, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <Type>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Hi I having same problem as you have, can you kindly put me right direction. here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376798/how-to-solve-auth-token-invalid-issue-from-angular-5-to-web-api

Comment: do I have to wrap user identity separate in addition to token or just token, at the movement I cannot these details other then authentication token at web api ???